# Converting Json format to newline delimited Json using Python

Tags: python

One of [BigQuery limitations for loading data from Json](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#limitations) is:

```
JSON data must be newline delimited
```

I have this code:

```
def create_jsonlines(self, original):
    if isinstance(original, str):
        original = json.loads(original)
    return '\n'.join([json.dumps(item) for _, item in original.items()])
```

This writes regular compressed json  to Google Storage:

```
regular = prefix + '/regular.json.gz'      
 storage.Bucket('bucket').item(regular).write_to(gzip.compress(bytes((data),encoding='utf8')), 'application/json')
```

This writes regular compressed json to Google Storage:

```
 newline = prefix + '/newline.json.gz'   
 storage.Bucket('bucket').item(newline).write_to(gzip.compress(bytes((self.create_jsonlines(data)),encoding='utf8')), 'application/json')
```

The regular json is **OK**. it contains everything that it should. But I can't really use it because this format is not supported by BigQuery.

The newline json is **not OK**. Lots of data is missing.. clearly I'm converting it wrong.

`data` is a dump as follows:      `data = json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True)`

How can I fix the create_jsonlines function?

Comment: That looks a lot like [my code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51595484/4799172) :) I'm not sure what exactly you're asking here. Can you illustrate the issue?

Comment: `json.dump(s)` takes the `indent` argument. If set to 0 or negative, it will insert newlines.

Comment: @roganjosh Could be :)   data contains complex structure of 21537 records (dicts and arrays in each record)  When I load the new line json to big query I see only 2401 rows and the data looks weird. Many columns are missing too.

Comment: @roganjosh Is there a way to make the create_jsonlines give the keys in sorted matter? Just like json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True) does? This will help to find the issue

Comment: My original answer does sort the keys and you've removed that part. I also have a feeling that you're misdiadnosing the problem but I'm not an expert in Big Query and can't test right now sorry :/

Comment: @roganjosh mm you don't have to be expert.. BigQuery auto detect the schema and rows from the Json. What it detects is wrong... when I'm looking at the original Json it's correct.. But I can't see inside the new line Json because there are no software that shows it. When I open it on notepad It seems that data is missing or misplaced...